How to conditionally show JSX element without re-render in ReactJS
Is there something similar to v-show from vuejs in reactjs?
I would like to have elements be shown or hidden based on the state of a variable, without the elements been re-rendered each time.
For example I am currently doing something that is similar to v-if in vuejs which looks like this dummy example
<>
    { state == "blue" && <Blue /> }
    { state == "red"  && <Red /> }
</>

The main issue I have is that the elements being rendered contain a lot of images, which get reloaded with each change.
If there isn't a v-show equivalent, how do I hide and show the elements without the elements reloading all the images each time?

I believe you want to do conditional rendering in react but don't want to re-render the images, You can use CSS for conditional rendering. You can toggle the visibility of elements without causing re-renders by simply toggling a class that hides or shows the elements. You can also try using useMemo hook

@RavinaSarda I have the same questions to you as a posted under the answer below. Does using style to hade and show elements not mean that all elements will be loaded to the DOM even if they are never "called". AFAIK v-show only renders the element lazily.

I am riding with @RaveenaSarda's answer. Toggling the css display property is what vshow does under the hood. So the elements are rendered in the dom but not visible until the condition to show is met. I would say you should just toggle between display: none and block if you are not animating the elements when they become visible. If you care about animating then you can use visibility.
